# find if product exists and if so, check if user exists in product array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When a user clicks a button, their userId and the product ID gets send to my query below. I want to check if that product exists, and if it does then check if a particular userId exists in an array of objects within the same document. I have tried the below but when I test it with other products where the userId is not present in the array, it is telling me that the user exists. So, it seems to be checking all products instead of just the one I am passing the product ID of.

```
Product.findById(productId).then(product => {
  if (!product) {
    console.log("no product found");
  }
  return Product.find({ "requests.userId": userId })
    .then(result => {
      if (result === undefined || result.length == 0) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "You can add it!" });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "You cannot add this again!" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is find a product that satisfies 2 conditions simultaneously:

1. Has a specific id
2. Has a specific string in the `requests` array filed

What your query is doing is testing the 2 conditions individually. First, you find the product and then you test if there's *any* product out there that satisfies condition 2.

To apply both conditions to the same product, use a single query:

```
Product.find({ _id: productId, 'requests.userId': userId })
  .then(product => {
    if (product) {
      const [result] = product; // take the first matched item
      // ... do stuff with result
    }
  })
```

Alternatively you could do all of this in memory:

```
 Product.findById(productId).then(product => {
    if (!product) {
      console.log("no product found");
      // ... potentially send an error here
      return;
    } 

    // find a match in memory
    const [result] = product.requests.filter(uid => uid === userId);
    if (result) {
      // ...
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks so much for this. I edited my original question (not sure if you can see it yet, says it needs a review?) Anyway, I posted it so you could please let me know if it's okay. Let me know if you can't see the edit and I will post the code in a comment

Comment: Glad to help :). Performance wise, the first example should be better. I had to reject your edit because you edited my answer with question clarifications, not the question :)

Comment: ah okay. I see. Not sure if it will fit here, but I just wanted to check if this was okay:  `Product.find({ _id: productId, "requests.userId": userId })
    .then(product => {
      if (!product === undefined || !product.length == 0) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "You cannot add this again!" });
        console.log(product);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "go ahead!" });
        console.log(product);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again, you're a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 1):

First, Ln 4, you are trying to check user ID in complete Product object from Mongo schema.

If your userId is stored within every individual product,
Then change Ln 4, Product to product.